# Add an initial text in textarea in two lines (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add an initial text in textarea in two lines
[image]

and to clear textarea on focus.
I tried to use this code

```
var startVal = 'Additional info: <br > text text text';
    var messBox = $('.textarea-1').val(startVal);

    messBox.on('focus blur', function(){
        var curVal = $.trim($(this).val());
        if(curVal == startVal) {
        $(this).val('');
        } else if(!curVal){
        $(this).val(startVal);
        }
    });
```

but it shows `<br>` tag inside my text and doesn't migrate the second row on new line.

How to make it work?

Comment: Use `\n` instead of `<br>`

Comment: You should post that as an answer @techfoobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: Use `\n` instead of `<br>`

```
var startVal = "Additional info:\ntext text text";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tw5Ge/)